# MySQL combine the result of 3 select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with a supposedly simple select query in MySQL, here's the scenario:
I have 3 tables 'Student', 'PresenceRecords1' and 'PresenceRecords2' with the following data,

*Student

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ sex  ║ firstname ║ lastname ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ masc ║ john      ║ doe      ║
║  2 ║ fem  ║ lisa      ║ simpson  ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

*PresenceRecords1

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ 1student_id║    date    ║ points ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ 2014-01-01 ║      1 ║
║  2 ║          2 ║ 2014-01-01 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║          1 ║ 2014-01-02 ║      5 ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ 2014-01-03 ║      1 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

*PresenceRecords2

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ student_id ║    date    ║ points ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ 2013-01-01 ║     10 ║
║  2 ║          1 ║ 2011-02-01 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║          1 ║ 2014-02-02 ║      5 ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ 2014-03-02 ║     15 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

I'm supposed to query the tables and got the following result:

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════╦══════════════╗
║ student_firstname ║ student_lastname ║ score ║ lastpresence ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║ john              ║ doe              ║    22 ║ 2014-02-02   ║
║ lisa              ║ simpson          ║    17 ║ 2014-03-02   ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════╩══════════════╝
```

this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    s.first_name as student_firstname,
    s.last_name as student_lastname,
    SUM(pr1.score + pr2.score) as prpoints,
    MAX(pr1.date) as maxdatepr1,
    MAX(pr2.date) as maxdatepr2
FROM
    student AS s
        INNER JOIN
    PresenceRecords1 AS pr1 ON s.id = pr1.1student_id
        INNER JOIN
    PresenceRecords2 AS pr2 ON pr1.1student_id = pr2.student_id
group by s.id
```

and I'm getting this result:

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║ STUDENT_FIRSTNAME ║ STUDENT_LASTNAME ║ PRPOINTS ║           MAXDATEPR1           ║           MAXDATEPR2            ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ john              ║ doe              ║       50 ║ January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 ║ February, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 ║
║ lisa              ║ simpson          ║       32 ║ January, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 ║ March, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000    ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the long post, [here is a SQLFIDDLE of my problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3901b).

Comment: The right direction starts with re-designing your db so there is only one table for PresenceRecords.

Comment: I would highly suggest to use ANSI standard `GROUP BY`

Comment: It might be useful to show what your intended goal is more than what you're getting without a clue as to your destination.

Comment: @DanBracuk I know that, the thing is I've not made this db and this was presented to me as a problem to solve.
I've considered using a FULL OUTER JOIN to get all the data from the tables, but MySQL has no such thing - or at least the version I have to work with - and the result from an UNION ALL isn't also near the results I'm aiming because I only get the results from PresenceRecords1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`,but i ask you to change your schema if you can store the data in one table for presence records rather saving them in individual table

```
SELECT 
    s.first_name as student_firstname,
    s.last_name as student_lastname,
    SUM(pr.score ) as prpoints,
    MAX(pr.date) as maxdatepr1    
 FROM   student AS s
JOIN 
(
SELECT 1student_id sid,score,date FROM PresenceRecords1
UNION 
SELECT student_id sid,score,date FROM PresenceRecords2
) pr ON(pr.sid =s.id)

group by s.id
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3901b/14)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id,s.sex,s.first_name,s.last_name, SUM(x.score),MAX(x.date) FROM student s
JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM presencerecords2
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM presencerecords1
 ) x
ON x.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```